# Is there a way to prevent rollback only in spring's finally statement?

Tags: spring, exception, transactions, try-catch, rollback

Assume the code is written as below.

```
@Transactional
public void test() {

    try {
        someA_insert()
        ...
        
        thow new Exceptions();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ...
        thow new Exceptions();    -- 1)
    }
    finally {
        //someB_insert();
        test2();
    }

@Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void test2() {
   someB_insert();
}
```

After executing the logic of inserting A (someA_insert), it meets Thow and handles rollback.

And then insert B in finally(someB_insert)

However, not only A, which I thought was rollbacked, but both A and B are rollbacked.

Is there any way to prevent rollback only at finally? Is it physically impossible?

(And if you omit the statement in 1), neither A nor B will be rolled back ;( )

Comment: No, as `test` is the transactional unit and as it is all or nothing you cannot partially commit a transaction. If you want to execute and insert only B then you need to create a new transaction just for that statement.

Comment: I've changed the question a bit since the answer said to create a new transaction.
I thought that using @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW) would create a new transaction even if there was a transaction from the parent (test() in this case). But the behavior is still the same. Can you take another look at what I'm missing?

Comment: It is an i nternal method call and thus doesn't pass through the AOP created proxy and thus no `@Transactional`. You either need to manually do this, or move the method to a different class or use load/compile timeweaving with AspectJ to make it work.